# .NET Core Gulp Minfiy/Bundled CSS file size reduces in release mode compared to debug

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a .net core MVC web app application where I serve two Gulp-minified and bundles CSS files **vender.bundle.css(313KB**) and **app.bundle.css(789KB)** after bundling. These are the file sizes at build location in both Debug and Release bin.

I serve these files from **_Layout.cshtml** with the below razor html.

```
<link asp-href-include="~/content/css/vendor.bundle.css"  asp-append-version="true" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link asp-href-include="~/content/css/app.bundle.css" asp-append-version="true"  rel="stylesheet" />
```

I know that asp-append-version cache busts the css files. But when I look into the chrome network tab with a css filter, I found

**On Release mode**

1. *vender.min.css = 68.1KB*
2. *app.min.css = 183KB*

**On Debug Mode**

1. *vender.min.css = 313KBKB*
2. *app.min.css = 789KB*

Could anyone give an info on what is happening. I get the app working fine in the release mode with all css- nothing missing even when file size reduced to a forth.

Comment: I guess in debug mode your not minified bundles are served, did you try to open them

Comment: Nop.Thats not the issue.. I don't keep non minified file in the file served location. Also i get the minified file in both cases in the browser. The point to note is that I do not use aspnetcore bundling but use seperate gulp minify and concat.

Comment: I serve the app using IIS

Comment: did you check the content-lenght and content-encoding response headers ? It could be because it's gzipped in release mode and not in debug mode

Comment: What is that? I dont get you. Why do i check?

Comment: HTTP headers : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers

Comment: I saw the Content header content-encoding-gzip seems to be available on the release mode only. I dont understand what makes the difference.

Comment: perhaps the response is in this article : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: Gzip is a type of compression, which is disabled typically in development. The server first compresses the files, then sends them to the client, where the client then decompresses them. As a result, the transfer file size is reduced, sometimes dramatically.